# Differences between hdparm --read-sector and dd with "Current Pending Sectors"

Tags: hard-drive, dd, hdparm

*This was originally an "answer" to [How to use hdparm to fix a pending sector?](https://serverfault.com/questions/461203)*

I'd been getting SMART notifications for the same "Current Pending Sector" for days.
The `dd` solutions around weren't resolving anything (they'd appear to zero data and re-write it but didn't effect the smart status).  *Be warned, I am no guru* on this,
just cargo-culting commands from forums.

The `dd` commands I used without changing the situation:

```
# read to file (all cmds ran w/o errors)
dd if=/dev/sdb of=bl.$BLOCK bs=1024 count=1 iflag=direct skip=$BLOCK
# zero out
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=1024 count=1 conv=noerror,sync seek=$BLOCK
# read the zeroes back
dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/stdout bs=1024 count=1 iflag=direct skip=$BLOCK | xxd
# write real data back out
dd if=bl.$BLOCK of=/dev/sdb bs=1024 count=1 iflag=direct seek=$BLOCK
# verify they match
dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/stdout bs=1024 count=1 iflag=direct skip=$BLOCK | xxd \
 | diff - <(xxd bl.$BLOCK)
# still have the Current_Pending_Sector error
smartctl -A /dev/sdb | grep Pend
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000 .. 1
```

The hdparm commands that cleared the Current_Pending_Sector count:

```
hdparm --read-sector $BLOCK /dev/sdb # data (didn't seem to match dd out)
# this was very slow on the first block
hdparm --write-sector $BLOCK /dev/sdb
hdparm --read-sector $BLOCK /dev/sdb # zeros
smartctl -A /dev/sdb | grep Pend
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000  .. 0
```

I didn't get any read/write errors with any these command, so the absence of errors
may just be the drive is able to effectively cover them up somehow.

Also, running the `dd` ones again would appear to restore the data,
but even then the `hdparm --read-sector` would show zeros.
I'm interpreting this as the hdparm talking to the drive at a lower level
and forcing the Pending writes, but dd just sees the drives remapped results...
is that what could be going on?

**Update** [A random post noting the difference between hdparm and dd output](http://sourceforge.net/p/hdparm/discussion/461704/thread/ce9e2318/).
hdparm-9.42 has a change to "force sector dumps (read-sector, identify, ..) to use le16 output format".

Comment: This has indeed stopped the daily SMART notifications

Comment: Remember that often you can still read the sector after enough (>10) tries. Then re-writing it with dd will cause a reallocation too, but you won’t have lost and data. Which is of course preferable. :)